# Bean injected in Quartz Job - NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a problem, injecting a CDI Bean in a Quartz schedule Job. This is the Code of the Job-Class.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

import com.example.controller.UserController;

@Log
public class SomethingNewScheduler implements Job {

    @Inject
    UserController userController;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        userController.doSomething();
    }
}
```

My UserController is defined as following:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;


import de.example.dao.UserDao;

@Log
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5922763136823308273L;
    @EJB
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void example(){
        userDao.getSomething();
    }
}
```

When I try to access the userController in my SomethingNewScheduler, i get a NullPointerException. Implementing Serializable in SomethingNewScheduler didn't solve the problem.

I'm using Wildfly 8.2.0 for my Application. Accessing UserController in a RestService worked perfectly fine.

Has anyone a idea, why it doesn't work here?

Comment: `SomethingNewScheduler` needs to be a CDI-aware managed bean (or an EJB) for the injection to take place.

Comment: For pass the object you want to use quarts bean JobDataMap. You could find lot of example on the net.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried, what's specified on this page: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjfzi.html) - I added `@Statless` to my Scheduler, and created an empty Constructor. The `UserController` ist still null.

Comment: You might consider using [EJB timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) instead of Quartz. These will integrate with CDI, etc with far less effort

Comment: Thanks Steve, EJB Timer works much better!